# drop down list on key up

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating a project management system in ROR. While creating a new project I need to add users belonging to that project. SO I have a textarea which when onkeyup will pop up a drop down list of users (starting the characters I type in textare)already in the database. I know it can be done via Ajax and jquery. But I am new to this. So could you please provide me some references for that??

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery UI's Autocomplete feature: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Does it have the option to select multiple items at a time. In textarea I need to select multiple users with coma seperated.

Comment: One of the demos shows it doing that with a comma between each value.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use multiple select instead of textarea. It is easy to use for `has_many` association.

To completely achieve your goals I also recommend to use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) for ajax and nice user experience.